# How is the name of the O'Hare delivery guy spelled?

Tags: character, the-lorax

At the end of *The Lorax* movie, there's the song "Let It Grow".

The delivery guy starts off the song with this:

> You don't know me, but my name's Cy,
>   I'm just the O'Hare, delivery guy.
>   But it seems like trees might be worth a try,
>   So I say, let it grow.

At least, that's how I interpret the name. However, the [internet](http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Cy_the_O%27Hare_Delivery_Guy) seems to disagree. Googling, there seem to be a lot of dissenting opinions on how to spell his name - is it Cy? Sai? Si? Psy? (See also the totally messed up [wiki page](http://seuss.wikia.com/wiki/Cy_the_O%27Hare_Delivery_Guy).)

Is there any canon info on how his name is actually spelled?

Comment: IMDB has it as "Cy"...but this seems like trivia to me. Why is this *important*.

Answer (score 2):

"Cy" is a [standard English abbreviation](https://www.behindthename.com/name/cy) for Cyrus or Cyril.  In Persian, it means "Master" or "Lord".  This is most likely the correct spelling of the person's name in the song.

"Sai" is mainly only used in India, while "Si" and "Psy" aren't commonly used in any language, though are sometimes used in the Far East.